# Check Mark doesn't become visible on trigger

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a simple CheckBox, in an Items Control - That is invisible if not checked and the mouse isn't over it the parent grid. But is visible if checked or mouse is over the grid.

The problem is, when the CheckBox is checked, the box stays visible but the check-mark disappears if the mouse isn't over the grid.

The code:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

**How do I keep the CheckMark visible in the CheckBox when the mouse moves away?** As you can see in the example below, the mouse is over the center of the three, but the other two are checked as well.

[image: The checkbox on the app]

Comment: I am guessing that it has something to do with your custom `CheckBox` template that you're using. With default template it works fine. Can you update the question with `CheckBox` template?

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the [MetroWindow UI Lib](http://mahapps.com/controls/metro-window.html) I'll have to check into, thanks.

Comment: when exactly do you wan't the mouse to be visible ?